# How to execute a program from an unhosted HTML file without using Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I'm attempting to create a front-end to launch several programs using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. My problem, however, is that the only ways that I can find to run a file either rely on Internet Explorer (Which I am not going to use) or download a new copy of the file.

Basically, I want to click a button or an image (Not 100% sure which one yet) and then run the program at the specified location. This isn't actually being hosted on a webserver; I'm just doing it because I make crappy GUIs in other languages, and HTML is comparatively easy.

This is also on Windows 7, if that has relevance.

Comment: [HTML isn't a standalone language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), it is a markup language that defines a structure for a browser, i.e. it needs a browser to render it. So you either have to use an existing browser, like IE, or write your own. Obviously writing your own is somewhat difficult o_O , so your going to have to use another browser to render your HTML.

Comment: Are you looking for [HTAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)?

Comment: Liam, I said without using Internet Explorer; not any browser. There are ways to launch exe programs in ONLY Internet Explorer, and I don't want to use those.

Comment: @georg You should post that as an answer. I've seen HTAs used for this very purpose, in fact.

Comment: HTAs also are not what I'm looking for, as they require the use of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar last year and used [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) for it, it´s a webkit browser with integrated node.js functions.
It has its own executable and has access to your filesystem through node.
It was fun and easy to use, maybe give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If running your HTML files in a browser using the file:// protocol isn't an option, choose the technology you're the most comfortable with and look for a way to display webpages through it.

For instance you can have a look at:

- WPF WebBrowser component (if you know a bit about .Net)
- Java FX2 WebView (if you're more of a java guy)
  etc...